# Need test case to find missing values for Name

Tags: sql-server

The following table has sample data

```
declare @test table(
   Name      varchar(30) not null,
   Product_1 varchar(10) not null,
   Product_2 varchar(10) not null,
   Product_3 varchar(10) not null,
   Product_4 varchar(10) not null
)

insert into @test values('A', 'AB',  'BC',  '',    'FG')
insert into @test values('B', 'EF1', 'EF2', 'EF3', '')
insert into @test values('C', 'ZA1', 'ZA2', 'ZA3', 'ZA4')
insert into @test values('D', '',    'ER',  'TZ1', 'GB1')

select * from @test
```

it has the following data:

[image]

I need a test case in Sql to find Missing Product's for Names and Each Name has Product must have Product before new product 
For example,
A has missing Product at 3 and it has in 4, Failed
B has missing Products until 3 but missing at 4, Pass
C has product's , Pass
D has missing Product at 1, Fail

Could you help me to display Output like below:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, and why didn't it work? if you need it, please at least show us your efforts. Stack Overflow isn't a free coding server; please don't treat it like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select name, 
       min(case when val = '' and next_val <> '' 
            then 'FAILED' 
            else 'PASS' 
       end) 
from   ( select *, lead(val) over ( partition by name order by col ) next_val from @test
         unpivot
         ( val for col in (Product_1, Product_2, Product_3, Product_4) ) as unpvt 
       ) A
group  by name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like below , but you need to set  your conditions carefully 
 for both failure and success : 
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8149f/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test (
   Name varchar(30) not null,
   Product_1 varchar(10) not null,
   Product_2 varchar(10) not null,
   Product_3 varchar(10) not null,
   Product_4 varchar(10) not null
)

insert into test values('A', 'AB', 'BC', '', 'FG')
insert into test values('B', 'EF1', 'EF2','EF3','')
insert into test values('C', 'ZA1', 'ZA2', 'ZA3','ZA4')
insert into test values('D', '', 'ER','TZ1','GB1')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Name,
CASE
    WHEN Product_1 = '' THEN 'FAILED'
    WHEN Product_2 = '' THEN 'FAILED'
    WHEN Product_3 = '' THEN 'FAILED'
    WHEN Product_4 = '' THEN 'PASS'
    ELSE 'PASS'
END AS Testing
FROM test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8149f/4/0)**:

```
| Name | Testing |
|------|---------|
|    A |  FAILED |
|    B |    PASS |
|    C |    PASS |
|    D |  FAILED |
```